# Ahorrar clases en CSS

Tags: html, css

Resulta que estoy haciendo unos botones outline, normales, y limpios.
Los normales tienen `background-color`, los outlines sólo border, y los limpios sólo color, también tengo atributos de colores, mi intención es que ese atributo sólo se use en *html*, por ejemplo:

```
<button --color-blue></button>
```

Lo que en *css* sería:

```
[--color-blue] {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

Pero no sé como hacer para que eso se adapte a los botones outline y limpios, porque les pone `background-color` y el texto en blanco, ¿habría algún tipo de condicional sólo - CSS? cómo

```
[--color-blue] {
  button.clean {
    backround-color: transparent;
    color: blue
  }
  button.outline {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Seria bueno que pusieras tu HTML.  Por el momento se me ocurre que uses clases.

Answer (score 5):

No, en `CSS3` no existen los condicionales, sin embargo existen otro tipo de extensiones con pre-compiladores como [less](http://lesscss.org/) y [sass](https://sass-lang.com/). Preferentemente yo prefiero `SASS` ya que tienen bastante funciones.
Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo sería en este lenguaje.

```
button {
  &[--color-blue] {
    color: blue;
  }
  &.clean {
    backround-color: transparent;
    color: blue;
  }
  &.outline {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: blue;
  }
}
```

---

A continuación te dejo un ejemplo funcionando con `SASS` en un [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5a8k2bo7/) para que puedas probarlo.

Answer (score 2):

Las posibles sintaxis en CSS son:

```css
button[--color-blue].clean{
  backround-color: transparent;
  color: blue
}
button[--color-blue].outline{
   background-color: transparent;
   border-color: blue;
}

[--color-red]
   button.clean {
   backround-color: transparent;
   color: red;
   }
[--color-red]
   button.outline{
   background-color: transparent;
   border-color: red;}
   }
```

```html
<button --color-blue class="outline">color blue</button>
<button --color-blue class="clean">color blue</button>

<div --color-red>
<button class="outline">color red</button>
<button class="clean">color red</button>
<div>
```

Como bien dice [Kleith](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/66539/kleith), si deseas/necesitas escribirlo de otra manera tendrás que usar un preprocesador. 
Cambios frecuentes o anidados complejos que puedan ser una pesadilla de copiar y pegar son los casos mas usuales.